# Unpack binary data with python

Tags: python, arrays, struct, unpack, uint16

I would like to unpack an array of binary data to `uint16` data with Python.

Internet is full of examples using `struct.unpack` but only examples dealing with binary array of size 4.

Most of these examples are as follow (`B` is a binary array from a file)

```
U = struct.unpack("HH",B[0:4]);
```

So i tried to unpack an array of size 6:

```
U = struct.unpack("HHH",B[0:6]);
```

It works.

But how to do if I want to unpack an array of size `L` (`L` is pair)?
I tried that:

```
U = struct.unpack("H"*(L/2),B[0:L]);
```

but it doesn't work, prompter gives me an error (for `L=512` for example):

```
struct.error: unpack requires a string argument of length 512
```

This message is strange because if i want to unpack a binary array to `uint16`, I need a string `"HHH...HHH"` of half size of this array...

I would be very grateful if someone could provide me with some help.

---

I progress a little bit... In fact, i tried:

```
U = struct.unpack("H"*8,B[0:8]);
```

It works.

```
U = struct.unpack("H"*10,B[0:10]);
```

It works.

```
U = struct.unpack("H"*222,B[0:444]);
```

It still works

```
U = struct.unpack("H"*223,B[0:446]);
```

It doesn't work! and it never works for size bigger than 446

Hope it will help anyone to answer me.

---

@MarkRansom I checked len(B) and in fact, the length is 444. I was so sure that B is an array of size 512 because B comes from :  `B = f.read(512)` where F is a 8000-bytes-size file. So a problem with read()... Thanks for this answer! But if someone has a help to unpack binary array of size L, i would be grateful

Comment: It would be better if you would do copy & paste. I don't think you examples work: string indexing works with `[]`, not with `()`. So what do you really do?

Comment: Did you check the length of your `B`? Is it possible that it hasn't 512 bytes?

Comment: Print `len(B)`, it will probably be illuminating.

Comment: struct.unpack_from("H", B) doesn't work? maybe you'll need to write: struct.unpack_from("%dH"%(len(B)/2), B)

Comment: B[0:446] == B[0:444] if len(B) is 444. Past 444 your string is too short.

Comment: from [`file.read()` docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.read): *"Read at most size bytes from the file (less if the read hits EOF before obtaining size bytes)."* i.e., `f.read(512)` can return less than `512` bytes.

Answer (score 13):

Use array.fromstring or array.fromfile (see http://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html ):

```
import array
U = array.array("H")
U.fromstring(B)
```

Answer (score 9):

Variable length version of the same thing:

```
n = 999
U = struct.unpack(str(n)+"H", B)
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to unpack n elements from binary data, you specify the number of elements together with the datatype. For n=999:

```
U = struct.unpack("999H", B)
```